# Horizontal list (ul) with multiline list item?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a horizontal list (for a nav bar) and i want an individual list item to be multilined. I tried using a `<br />` but that causes the entire list to skip a line

Here's what i got for html :

```
<ul class="nav_list">
        <li><a href="#">Home<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar/Bat Mitzvah<br />Tutoring<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Early <br />Childhood<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home<a></li>

</ul>
```

and css:

```
.nav_list {
    float:right;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:55px;
    width:510px;
}

.nav_list li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;

}

.nav_list li a {
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: arial;
    color:#b64366;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px 4px 5px 10px;
    background-image:url('../images/nav_divider.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;

    }
```

And this is what it should look like (photoshop):
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3jWwH/

The Html had some errors, like the 'a' tag wasn't ended correctly '/a'.

'br /' works fine, you just have to add float:left to '.nav_list li'

Also I think you should apply padding to 'li' instead of 'a'.

Is this correct?

Comment: This example was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/zXzXn/1/

**CSS:**

```
.nav_list {
    float:right;
    margin-top:55px;
}

.nav_list li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;

}

.nav_list li a {
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: arial;
    color:#b64366;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:4px 10px 5px 10px;
    background-image:url('../images/nav_divider.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;

}
.nav_list li a:hover{
    border-bottom:2px solid #b64366;
}
```

​

Comment: Close the <a> tags & it will work. your Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zXzXn/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width to each of the list elements to constrain them to a certain width. This will cause the words to split to multiple lines.

```
.nav_list li a {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Then add a bottom border to make the underline on hover.

```
.nav_list li :hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b64366;
}
```